# Как скачать нормально php и установить?

Tags: php

Скачал [отсюда](http://windows.php.net/download/) файл VC9 x86 Non Thread Safe, распаковал, нашёл файл php.exe, запустил его, но при открытии файла вылазит сообщение с заголовком - точка входа не найдена, тот же самый результат получается и с другими запускаемыми приложениями в этой папке.

Что делать, может я не тот установочный файл закачал? Может надо какие-то пути в файлах прописать? или я не тот файл для запуска жму?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сам по себе инстал PHP дает возможность запускать скрипты только в [консольном режиме](http://php.net/manual/ru/install.windows.commandline.php). Для использования PHP в разработке веб-сайтов еще, как минимум, нужен веб-сервер. Например, [Apache](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache) или [Nginx](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx). Веб-сервер обрабатывает HTTP-запросы из браузера и возвращает результат в виде HTML. Веб-сервер может возвращать содержимое как статичных html-файлов, так и результат работы php-скриптов. Для этого, этот самый веб-сервер нужно [сконфигурировать](http://popoff.donetsk.ua/text/donntu/pssbd/install.html) на обработку с помощью php-интерпретатора.

Если вы только начинаете разбираться во всем этом, рекомендую [Denwer](http://www.denwer.ru/). Он включает в себя все вышеперечисленные инсталы, устанавливается быстро, и не требует глубокой настройки конфигов.

Comment: денвер у меня уже есть, но для более глубокого изучения мне порекомендовали установить всё это самому

Comment: с этой бедой я справился установил php, но есть один вопрос
У меня уже установлен apache но при установке php у меня небыло вариантов подключения к нему, пришлось выбрать то что было установленно по умолчанию, сможет ли теперь apache подключится к php?

Comment: Инсталяция PHP сама ничего никуда не подключит. Суть установки сводится к тому, чтобы распаковать архив в заданную папку. Прикручивать PHP к Apache нужно самостоятельно, путем правки конфига httpd.conf. В сети на эту тему тонны статей.

Comment: Для глубокого изучения лучше установить это все на линуху.

Comment: Не уверен, что первое знакомство с кодингом на PHP нужно начинать с установки линукса, на него Apache, и сверху PHP. Это, безусловно, очень полезный и необходимый опыт, но не на начальном этапе. Цель написать "Hello World" оттягивается на неопределенный срок.